# Access violation when searching through a file

Tags: c, search, strstr

This is my algorithm for searching a term into a file.

```
void ricerca_file(char* frase){

char* prelievo = "";
file = fopen("*userpath*\\file.bin", "rb");
while((fgets(prelievo, sizeof(prelievo), file)) != NULL){
    if((strstr(prelievo, frase)) != NULL)
        printf("frase trovata!\n");
} 

fclose(file);
printf("%s", prelievo);}
```

i ask the input of `frase` in this way:

```
char* frase = "";
printf("insert the term that you want to search..");
scanf("%s", frase);
```

and then i call the function with:

```
ricerca_file(frase);
```

The compiler gives me this error after i write the input (e.g the number 2):

> prove1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00F67BC3.
>
> If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely
>   continued.

What am i doing wrong?

if it wasn't clear, i'm learning. But i didn't really got how to manage the search of a term into a file.
I guess that with this algorithm i can miss lots of matches because if i search for "hello", with the strstr function that moves 5 characters per cycle if i have a file with a text like this "abchelloabc" he will first find "abche" and will not find anything, while after the first cycle it will go to the "lloab" part and then "c". Am i right thinking that it works like that and this is wrong?

Comment: In addition to the answers below: if your file is binary you cannot use `fgets` for obvious reasons, and if your file is a text file you need to use the `"r"` open mode instead of `"rb"`.

Answer (score 4):

`prelievo` points to a string literal. This is constant data that cannot be written to. And `sizeof(prelievo)` will be 2 or 4 (or whatever size pointers are on your system), which is not what you want.

You'll need to instead point `prelievo` to an array of characters that *can* be modified:

```
char prelievo[1000];
```

The same problems and solution apply to `frase`:

```
char frase[1000];
```

Comment: thanks! that worked. But i have some questions. The output showed me 3 instances of the term that i searched (there were only 2 of then); is this code supposed to print all the occurrences? I don't think so.. or does strstr append the chars found to the output string?

Comment: anyway i thought i was correct about my last doubt. Don't strstr() moves of the size of the second int parameter of the function? shouldn't it miss certain words?

Comment: so does strstr() print by itself the string first if it finds a match?

Comment: and if i would search on an entire file, what dimension should i've put on strstr? sizeof(file)?

Comment: Again, `strstr()` doesn't take any dimensions.

Comment: anyway i didn't mean strstr() for the int parameter thing before.. i had got confused with fgets().. the question is the same: shouldn't it miss some datas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually provide memory to save the string you scan into. Try something like this instead:

```
char frase[80];
printf("insert the term that you want to search..");
fgets(frase, 80, stdin);
```

This allocates enough space for 80 characters and then reads one line of input.

Please also check the results of all these functions: If they return an error, you should act appropriately.

Comment: Thanks! what is the better option between fgets and scanf?

Comment: @questioner Generally, use `fgets` when you want to read an entire line, use `scanf` when you want to parse fields within a line.

Answer (score 0):

what am I doing wrong:

regarding:

```
char* prelievo = "";
file = fopen("*userpath*\\file.bin", "rb");
while((fgets(prelievo, sizeof(prelievo), file)) != NULL){
    ...
```

The call to fgets() needs to have a pointer to a buffer as its' first parameter.

The 'prelievo' is only an uninitalized pointer.

suggestion 1)

```
char* prelievo = malloc( 1024 );
if ( prelievo ) {
    file = fopen("*userpath*\\file.bin", "rb");
    while((fgets(prelievo, sizeof(prelievo), file)) != NULL){
```

suggestion 2)

```
char prelievo[1024];
file = fopen("*userpath*\\file.bin", "rb");
while((fgets(prelievo, sizeof(prelievo), file)) != NULL){
```

Comment: thank you! i didn't know that i could have initialized a pointer directly with malloc. What is the better option? using a pointer with malloc or an array?

Comment: @questioner It's totally up to you. In this case I'd go for a fixed sized array as in suggestion 2. Suggestion 1 is plain wrong because here `sizeof(prelievo)` wont be 1024 but rather 4 or 8 depending on your platform.

Comment: Suggestion 1 is plain wrong because here `sizeof(prelievo)` wont be 1024 but rather 4 or 8 depending on the platform.

Comment: so sizeof(prelievo) it's like using sizeof(char)?

Answer (score 0):

This answer is not exactly related to your problem, but because you already got your Answers i will try to explain you about some problems if you ignore them.

If we do not check for errors/return and the program works fine this does not mean that the program is ok or safe.
Let's take the following scenario as an Example.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

char *printFile(char *fileName){
    size_t length,size;
    char *buffer;
    FILE *file;

    file = fopen (fileName , "r" );


    fseek (file , 0 , SEEK_END);
    length = (size_t)ftell (file);
    fseek (file , 0 , SEEK_SET);

    buffer = malloc(length);
    if (buffer == NULL){
        fputs ("Memory error",stderr);
        exit (2);
    }


    size = fread (buffer,1,length,file);
    if (size != length){
        fputs ("Reading error",stderr);
        exit(3);
    }

    fclose (file);
    return buffer;
}

int main (void) {
    char *fileName = "test.txt";
    char *stringToSearch = "Addams";
    char *fileContent = printFile(fileName);

    if (strstr(fileContent, stringToSearch)){
        printf("%s was Found\n",stringToSearch);
    }else{
        printf("%s was not Found\n",stringToSearch);
    }

    free(fileContent);

    return 0;
}
```

The file **test.txt** has the following content:

> ```
> Michael Jackson
> Bryan Addams
> Jack Sparrow
> ```

So now if I run this program I get:

> Addams was Found

Everything seems to be ok, but what happens if I try to share this program with someone ? Or what happens if I try to run it on another computer ?
well:

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

OMG, what did just happen now ? Simple,the file **test.txt** is missing and i did not check that in my program that's why.

Lets move on and create that file and run that program again:

> Addams was not Found

Huh, I succeeded isn't ? Well not, valgrind has another opinion:

> ```
> ==3657== Invalid read of size 1
> ==3657==    at 0x4C32FF4: strstr (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
> ==3657==    by 0x400A2D: main (in /home/michi/program)
> ==3657==  Address 0x54202b0 is 0 bytes after a block of size 0 alloc'd
> ==3657==    at 0x4C2BBA0: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
> ==3657==    by 0x40095E: printFile (in /home/michi/program)
> ==3657==    by 0x400A16: main (in /home/michi/program)
> ```

What happens is that I try to read a file which was newly created without thinking if that file has some content and i performed a lot of codding on it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I usually use controls for files; now i didn't use any because i was mainly trying to understand the code. But hadn't known that this may have caused so serious errors, so thanks for the details!